# Random effects that are related to fixed effects

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

I am trying to compute a generalized linear mixed model whith my data. My response variable is the presence/ausence of copulation call in each copulation. I have 400 copulations produced by 30 different females and each one contributes disproportionally to the data, so I was controlling female ID as random effect. My predictor is male ranking, however, each female ONLY copulates with her leader male. Then, I was wondering if I can compute this model due to female ID is somehow related to male ranking as there is not variability between my predictor across each female.

Thanks!

Comment: Does each leader male copulate with more than one female?

Comment: Yes! they have a one-male multi-female units system, so there are 30 females organized in 8 male groups. Then, there are some females who share male ranking.

Comment: So, copulations nested in females nested in males, right? And you have a ranking variable for males and females(?).

Comment: Yes, that is the structure. And my predictors are proxies for rank male and female. Then, I think these predictors are constant across the copulations...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have nested data:

- 8 males, that differ in rank

  - multiple females for each male

    - multiple data points (copulations) for each male-female pair

This model can be estimated just fine, e.g. (using `lme4`)

```
glmer(call_present ~ 1 + male_rank + (1|female_id), family = binomial)
```

The intercept term that varies across females, `(1|female_id)`,
captures how the log-odds of a call occuring for female $f$, who is paired with male $m$, differs from the average log-odds for all females paired with that male.